# How to filter date stored in char field in django

Tags: django-models

How to filter date stored in char field in django, I am having char field storing value like "yyyy-mm-dd".

how to filter against date object in django

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you store `date` in `CharField` named `birthdate`
So you need to convert your CharField value to date string like this

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_date
converted_birthday = parse_date(birthdate)
```